# Why does the tensor product of matrix have this expression?

Tags: matrices

$(A\otimes B)^{i\alpha}_{\space\space\space j\beta} = A^{i}_{\space\space j}B^{\alpha}_{\space\space\beta}$

I have done some tests on 2 by 2 examples and this is not generally true.

[Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1x9ey.png)

Do i have the wrong interpretation of this formula?

Comment: I don't think it's clear what you're asking.  Maybe if you included one of your "tests" it would be more clear.

Comment: If i understand correctly, this is true. Can you show why this is not true?

Comment: In the test, the (3,3) entry of $(A\otimes B)^{i\alpha}_{\space\space\space j\beta}$ can only be decomposed into 1 or 3 for i or $\alpha$ (as i$\alpha$ = 3). But there is obviously no 3 in each matrix as they are 2 by 2.